# How do I delete custom images I made in my computer?

Tags: ev3, ev3-g

I created a custom image for a test, and everytime I download the program to my brick, the image shows up in the folder despite me not using a display program. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to go to the project tab (1) - it's the one with the wrench icon - and delete any unneeded items. Just select the item (2) and click the *Delete* button (3).

[image: screenshot]